# Where should I place my custom verify.txt file for my Mailman mailing list?

Tags: mailman

According to documentation, in order to customize the contents of the subscription confirmation email that gets send out when a user subscribes to a Mailman mailing list, you need to edit a file called `verify.txt`. This file is supposed to be in `/var/lib/mailman/lists/[name-of-mailing-list]/en`.

When I look in that directory, I only have two files, `listinfo.html` and `subscribeack.txt`. There is no `verify.txt` already there.

Am I looking in the right place?

If I make a new `verify.txt` file in that directory, will that automatically be picked up and used by Mailman? Would I need to change any other configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ubuntu? If so, look under /etc/mailman/en/ directory. The verify.txt under /etc/mailman/en/ is a general one for all lists, and I think you can copy it to your list-specific directory. (I wish I can just use comment function to ask about your OS, but I cannot according to my status.)